# Spark SQL - Finding the maximum value of a month per year

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have created a data frame which contains Year, Month, and the occurrence of incidents (count).

[image]

I want to find the month of each year had the most incident using spark SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions, if you want to use SQL:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per year, even if there are ties for the maximum count.  If you want all such rows in the event of ties, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: I know, it's hard work to answer questions quicker than anyone else, but sometimes you should read your answer before you post it and go to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, rank() over(partition by year order by cnt desc) rn from mytable t) t
where rn = 1
```

For each year, this gives you the row that has the greatest `cnt`. If there are ties, the query returns them.

Note that `count` is a language keyword in SQL, hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `cnt` in the query.

Comment: I am pretty new to Spark SQL, and I don't know much about window functions. Is there any way I can do it without the window function?

Comment: @kimhkh: there are other options, but this looks like the simplest approach here. I would recommend running the subquery first, so you can see the result and understands how it works. For example: `select t.*, rank() over(partition by year order by cnt desc) rn from mytable t order by year, rn`.